# Java : Changing a binary number bits 0's to 1's and 1's to 0's

Tags: java

I was wondering how would you change a binary number and reverse the 1's and 0's?  I know how to change an integer number into binary already

```
Example 1: 5 as a parameter would return 2
Steps: 5 as a binary is 101
          The complement is 010
          010 as an integer is 2
```

Code to change an integer to a binary number

```
import java.io.*;
public class DecimalToBinary{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
  BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  System.out.print("Enter the decimal value:");
  String hex = bf.readLine();

  int i = Integer.parseInt(hex);  


  String bynumber = Integer.toBinaryString(i);


  System.out.println("Binary: " + bynumber);
  }
}
```

if anyone code please help, thank you!

Comment: And explain what is the problem with your current code.

Comment: Noting is wrong with my code so far, i just need help on reversing the binary number Example : 101 = 010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the bitwise not function `~`.

```
int num = 0b10101010;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(num));         // 10101010
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((byte) ~num)); //  1010101 (note the absent leading zero)
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to explicitly convert it to binary.  You can use [**bitwise operators**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) for this.

Comment: Thanks, will be trying this now

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(numString);
i = ~i;
```

That should do it.

Comment: Well if it is an hex, then it should be parseInt(hex, 16), shouldn't it ?

Comment: The OP used hex to denote the string input. You are right, it should have a better name.